# How does the mobile developer get the design guide from the designer?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ui-design

Here is the situation:

When the designer finishes the UI design for the app and has to send over to the developer (who barely knows Photoshop or any kinds of creative program).

- How you the developer find out the design details? i.e. x, y, color, font size, etc.
- If the designer gives you the guide, what kinds of guide they provide you? (i.e. create manually on Ai and give to you as pdf? Using some website to create? Hand writing? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I also barely know Photoshop. Designer sends me just the psd file. I cut icons from there using the Photoshop extension [Cut&Slice me](http://www.cutandslice.me/). Text color and font size you can know with "Horizontal type tool" (first click where your layer with text then click to text in your image then in the top you will see color etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I can speak based on my experience as a designer, and as a developer. What kind of files we deliver typically depends on the developer. Some clients need spec documents that specify fonts, margins, etc. Sometimes we just deliver photoshop files. As long as the developer has the program, it's fairly easy to measure things, and to check font sizes - provided the file is well organized. This is only a very basic understanding level required.

Some apps do have decent export features - Adobe has Generate within Photoshop, and Sketch has a nice export feature as well.